# Optimal orbital tranfers: reference for statements & proofs

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations

I know that Pontryagin's contribution to optimal control in the 1950'ies was allegedly inspired by the then-nascent rocket industry and the question of how to get a rocket into orbit with minimum fuel.

My question is where one can find concrete statements and proofs for problems like...

1. What is the optimal tranfer orbit between two circular orbits of different radii (circular orbits around a single planet, the only attracting body in the problem, impulsive engine burns allowed): is it the [Hohmann tranfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit) if the radii differ only slightly and the [bi-elliptic tranfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-elliptic_transfer) for greater radius? In other words: give a complete phase-diagram of the optimal transfer orbit. (throughout the problem, "optimality" means minimal delta vee expended)
2. What is the optimal transfer orbit from a planetary surface, i.e. an initial orbit with a speed equal to zero or at least smaller than the orbital speed associated to that distance from the planet's center, to another circular orbit? (Impulsive burns allowed. Optimality again measured in delta vee and please ignore some of the real-world aspects like atmospheric drag, although the interior of the planet should be impermissible territory for the transfer orbit)